# Rails Caching, continue storing expired value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I have a long database query on one of our dashboard systems that I would like to cache as results do not need to be accurate in realtime but can give a "close enough" value from the cache.

I would like to do this without the user ever having to wait. I was looking at using something like

```
Rails.cache.write('my_val', 'val', :expires_in => 60.minutes)
```

to store this value, but I don't believe it gives the exact functionality that I want.  I would like to call with

```
 Rails.fetch('my_val') { create a background task to update my_val; return expired my_val}
```

It seems that my_val is removed from the cache when it expired though.  Is there any way to access this expired value or perhaps another built in mechanism that would enable this functionality?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you set your background task to update the value before it expires? That way the code never has to wait.

Comment: Well, if a background task is already running and it takes excessively long, such that the cache expires before it completes, I want to return the old value while it continues to run.

Comment: It's not doable. Once the cache expires the value is null and you can't access the previous one. Increase the expiration... or just don't set an expiration time for the cache entry. That way, the value will always be there and you can override the value using your background task once it finished running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

```
Rails.cache.write('my_val', 'val')
```

never expire

Now run your background job:

```
SomeLongJob.process
```

In the SomeLongJob.process job do this:

```
def SomeLongJob.process
  some_long_calculation = Blah.calc
  Rails.cache.write('my_val', some_long_calculation)
end
```

Now read the data with

```
def get_value
  val = Rails.cache.read('my_val', 'val')
end
```

Comment: is the `delete` line superfluous? I assume a `write` will overwrite any existing value atomically, avoiding any issue for cache hits between the `delete` and `write` lines.

Comment: That would work, I was trying to get away with one more scheduling job, but not the end of the world to have a rake task kicked off every hour or so.
I'd be even better if the cache would know when to update itself, an "on_experiation" block that gets called, but that'd probably be some pretty heavy monkey patching.

Answer (score 1):

The `:race_condition_ttl` option for `Rails.cache.fetch` is REALLY close to what you are looking for: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html#method-i-fetch

But from what I can tell, the first request is still blocked (it's just subsequent ones that get the old value while it's updating).  Not sure why they didn't go all the way with it.  It would be better if the pattern @drhenner mentioned was abstracted into an option like that, but I haven't seen one yet.